# Sed substitution on C-style (single-line) comment

Tags: regex, sed

I'm kind of confused as to why this isn't working.  I'm trying to do something a little more complicated, but the core of my problem comes down to matching a single-line C-comment.

Example `myfile`:

```
/* a comment */
```

Running:

```
sed 's|/\*\([.]*\)\*/|\1|' ./myfile
```

doesn't match/replace.

Why is that? I've broken it into parts and it seems to work on the individual pieces (opening `/*`, stuff, closing `*/`, and combinations (beginning/middle and middle/end), and that all works, but putting it together doesn't.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[.]*` is looking for a string of zero or more dots.  You want the `.` to be a metacharacter; remove the square brackets around it.

```
sed 's|/\*\(.*\)\*/|\1|' ./myfile
```

Note that this is a greedy matching algorithm; that's all the plain ordinary (POSIX) version of `sed` supports.  It means that:

```
XX /* comment1 */ YY /* comment2 */ ZZ
```

will output:

```
XX  comment1 */ YY /* comment2  ZZ
```

Fixing that with classic `sed` is sufficiently close to impossible to be not worth attempting.  If you have PCRE (Perl-compatible Regular Expression) support in your `sed`, you can use the non-greedy matching operators to treat that as two comments.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan.  It was meant to be more of a learning exercise than anything robust enough for use.  Thanks for the help though, this was driving me bonkers.